# Item с большим изображением и полосами прокрутки

Tags: qt, qml

Мне хотелось бы создать простой элемент, который бы отображал картинку и полосы прокрутки (размер изображения больше размера элемента) для изменения видимой части картинки. Думал, вот так получиться, но не сработало:

```
Flickable
{
    id: sceneWidget
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: 500
    height: 300
    clip: true
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn }
    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn }

    Rectangle
    {
        width: backgroundImage.sourceSize.width
        height: backgroundImage.sourceSize.height
        color: "#000000"
        clip: true

        Image
        {
            id: backgroundImage
            source: "file:///scene.png"
            clip: true
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полосы прокрутки заполнены полностью, хотя и видно только маленький кусочек изображения. Подскажите, как быть, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно просто указать следующие свойства Flickable:

```
contentWidth: backgroundImage.sourceSize.width
contentHeight: backgroundImage.sourceSize.height
```